# Problem calculating correlation in Python

Tags: python, correlation

I have the following data frame

[image]

I need to calculate a correlation matrix across all columns. The problem is: when I calculate two columns separately I get a different value than when I calculate all together for every pair using df.corr().

The way I constructed the data frame was by merging the first column with every other one, and this merging process resulted in different row lengths of two by two data frames.

For example: the first column (btc_logreturns) and the second columns (gold_logreturns) had 2000 rows originally, while btc_logreturns and ewz_logreturns had 2100 rows. But all columns together have 2459 rows.

Does the function .corr() account for NaNs when calculating the correlation? Is the length of the data frame a potential problem for the different correlation values I get?

Comment: Is the column alignment approriate (after concatenation)? It looks like you don't use a datetime index, just the regular integers. That could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in the fact that the indices of these data frames do not align, meaning that some indices that are present in one data frame are not present in the other and vice versa.

If the indices are indeed meaningful, use the result of the merged data frame. If on the other hand, the indices are not meaningful, merge the original data frames using `pd.concat([df_1, df_2], ignore_index=True)` which will ignore the indices in the original data frames.

Comment: I was already using pd.concat. Then, I tried what you suggested, but it did not work :/

Comment: I suggest you add the code you used, what the different outputs were, what you expected to happen and what exactly turned out to be different from what you expected.